# How to check version of the crypto module?

Tags: node.js

I am using `require('crypto')` and need to check version... How to?

There are an instruction for it?

I try also at terminal, `npm list -g  | grep -i crypt`, but nothing there, only things like "crypto-random-string@1.0.0".

The [official last release seems  v11.9.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases)

Comment: Crypto is a library provided by nodejs, so it always has the same version as nodejs itself.

Comment: Hi @tkausl, there are no instruction to get the value "v11.9.0"? See my link, there exist a version number, and I must check it to understand my bugs (!), because some are not bugs but only "old version problem".

Comment: Hi @pzaenger, my `node -v` is "v8.8.1", nothing about crypto's "v11.x" or "v10.x"

Comment: Then you need to upgrade your node to v11.x

Comment: BTW, Node.js version can be found via API inside a script via `process.version` or `process.versions.node`.

Comment: Thanks @vsemozhetbyt, was a clue... See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The first clue comes from @vsemozhetbyt, `process.versions.node`, that is, use the path from `process.versions`... You can access it also by terminal with `-p` option:

`node -p process.versions.openssl`

The [major and minor versions](https://semver.org/) of the crypto module are attached with the  openssl version.

PS: thanks from Sam Roberts to remember openssl.